# Failed to use "cl" even after environment variable set

Tags: c, visual-studio, environment-variables

So i'm trying to compile my helloworld.c file on my desktop using cl under "Administer: Developer Command Prompt for VS2015".

I figure it's environment var problem by doing some Google, and follow the link below to set it. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd.aspx)

But after i found and ran the VSVARS32 file under

```
"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools",
```

i still can't use my cl command, showing that

```
"'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

Please help me, any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You need to close and reopen cmd.exe when changing environment variables. This bit me a few times.

Comment: Thx for your suggustion, but still no luck, i tried it many times T_T

Comment: @a3f tried restarting my laptop, still no luck

Comment: the `cl` is a sub/internal facility of the gcc compiler/linker.  Much better to just run `gcc` rather than trying to perform an 'end run' around the proper usage of that facility.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks!, it solved my problem, thought cl is the only way to compile

Comment: @user3629249 `cl` is the command line utility for the Visual C++ compiler. `gcc` is a completely different compiler.